# Using Reduce() function in IOS9 swift2.0

Tags: ios, swift

I am in process of learning swift and web services.

When I tried to compile the following code in IOS 9, I get

> reduce is unavailable: call the reduce() method on the sequence

```
private class func urlWithName(name: String, var args: [String: String]) -> NSURL
{
    args["username"] = "ijoshsmith"
    let
    baseURL      = "http://api.geonames.org/",
    queryString  = queryWithArgs(args),
    absolutePath = baseURL + name + "?" + queryString
    return NSURL(string: absolutePath)!
}

private class func queryWithArgs(args: [String: String]) -> String
{
    let parts: [String] = reduce(args, [])
        {
            result, pair in
            let
            key   = pair.0,
            value = pair.1,
            part  = "\(key)=\(value)"
            return result + [part]
    }
    return (parts as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString("&")
}
```

So, I understand that I should covert reduce(args, []) to something like args.reduce(initial: T, combine:(T, Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T).
Can someone help me in explaining and converting it.

thanks.

Comment: The error the compiler gave means that - You can use the reduce method on arrays(sequence).The high order functions like, map(), reduce() & filter() are meant to be used with Sequence / Array.

Comment: Also Please follow this link : https://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/ to learn more about the higher order functions. Trust me they're very useful. :) HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax looks like this:

```
private class func queryWithArgs(args: [String: String]) -> String
{
    let parts: [String] = args.reduce([]) {
            result, pair in
            let
            key   = pair.0,
            value = pair.1,
            part  = "\(key)=\(value)"
            return result + [part]
    }
    return parts.joinWithSeparator("&")
}
```

I also updated your return value to avoid an `NSArray` cast.

You might also want to see Alamofire's [ParameterEncoding.swift](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/df525acf40245b17e260def5a24033be14190adc/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift), which has a more thorough approach to parameter encoding already written.

Answer (score 2):

> `let parts: [String] = reduce(args, [])`

You're trying to call `reduce` as a standalone function, but it's actually a method in the `SequenceType` protocol, which is adopted by `Array`. Assuming that `args` is the array to which you want to apply `reduce`, you'd call it like:

```
foo = args.reduce(t, f)
```

where `t` is the initial value and `f` is the combining function.

Comment: Just to add a point, the result of the reduce() will be of type 't'

Comment: A minor clarification: it's not a member function of arrays, it's part of `SequenceType`.

Comment: @AaronBrager `SequenceType` is the protocol that declares `reduce()`, but `Array` still has to provide the implementation. It's a good point to mention `SequenceType`, though, and I'll add that. Thanks.

Comment: If I recall correctly, it's implemented as a default protocol implementation, not on `Array`, according to a stack trace I looked at. I might be remembering wrong though.

Comment: [Here's the stack trace I was thinking of](http://imgur.com/q1bGpfW) - my interpretation might be wrong though. Let me know what you think

Comment: @AaronBrager Fair enough -- I'll change the language above. Cheers.